# Search a class that start with prefix inside getElementsByClassName iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to extract one class value that start with a prefix (val) So I have used document.getElementsByClassName to find all parents classes (CItem te1) and find inner classes value.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('CItem te1');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
            {
                var codice = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CCodPub')[0];
                var name = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CSubEv')[0];
                var realname = name.getElementsByTagName("span");
                var nom = realname[0];
                var quota = $('[class^="val"]').html();
                var league = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CEvento')[0];
                var signe = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CSegno')[0];
                alert (quota );
            }}
```

The problem that this code will return the same quota value for all the classes finded how can I execute this line :

var quota = $('[class^="val"]').html();  inside each item {items[i]}

This code must return 1.50 in the first alert and 1.90 in the second one

```js
function change() {
     var items = document.getElementsByClassName('CItem te1');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
                {
     var codice = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CCodPub')[0];
     var name = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CSubEv')[0];
     var realname = name.getElementsByTagName("span");
                    var nom = realname[0];
                    var quota = $('[class^="val"]').html();
     var league = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CEvento')[0];
     var signe = items[i].getElementsByClassName('CSegno')[0];
     alert (quota );
                    //alert('Code '+codice.innerHTML+' nom '+nom.innerHTML+' League '+league.innerHTML+' Signe '+signe.textContent);
                }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="change()">
<div class='CItem te1'>
                                    <div class="CInfo" title="Portugal - Taca de Portugal"></div>
                                    <div class="CCodPub">1039</div>
                                    <div class='CEvento'>Portugal - Taca de Portugal</div>
                                    <div class="CSubEv"><span id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_SE" title="Benfica  -  Guimaraes [at Estadio do Jamor]">Benfica  -  Guimaraes [at Estadio do Jamor]</span></div>
                                    
                                    
                                            <div class="COdds False">
                                                  
                                                <a id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_repCouponDetails_ctl00_LinkButton1" title="Remove from betslip" class="CDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('h$w$PC$cCoupon$repCoupon$ctl01$repCouponDetails$ctl00$LinkButton1','')"></a>
                                                <div class="CSegno" title='1'><span id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_repCouponDetails_ctl00_Label1" class="ClblSegno">Mark:</span>1</div>
                                                <div class='val_1'>1.50</div>
                                                <div class="DIQ" id="DIQ_5049570680">1|1.36|S|0</div>
                                                
                                           </div>
                                        
                                </div>
<div class='CItem te1'>
                                    <div class="CInfo" title="Portugal - Taca de Portugal"></div>
                                    <div class="CCodPub">1039</div>
                                    <div class='CEvento'>Portugal - Taca de Portugal</div>
                                    <div class="CSubEv"><span id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_SE" title="Benfica  -  Guimaraes [at Estadio do Jamor]">Benfica  -  Guimaraes [at Estadio do Jamor]</span></div>
                                    
                                    
                                            <div class="COdds False">
                                                  
                                                <a id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_repCouponDetails_ctl00_LinkButton1" title="Remove from betslip" class="CDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('h$w$PC$cCoupon$repCoupon$ctl01$repCouponDetails$ctl00$LinkButton1','')"></a>
                                                <div class="CSegno" title='1'><span id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_repCoupon_ctl01_repCouponDetails_ctl00_Label1" class="ClblSegno">Mark:</span>1</div>
                                                <div class='val_8'>1.90</div>
                                                <div class="DIQ" id="DIQ_5049570680">1|1.36|S|0</div>
                                                
                                           </div>
                                        
                                </div>
                              </body>
```

Comment: Show you html code

Comment: And `var quota = $('[class^="val"]').html();` this will return same result every time because this will find all classes with prefix val throughout dom every time. I think you should find it in a particular node

Comment: And also missing tagname selector index `name.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];` . show your html code

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: Already added thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple $.each() will do what you expect as I see you have included jQuery also in your answer. The css selector is correct you just iterate through the elements and fetch their inner text

```
$('[class^="val_"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Or simply, using javascript, but making use of the useful `document.querySelectorAll` function.

```
var elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="val_"]');

for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    alert(elementsArray[i].innerText);
}
```

This is the best resource to learn more about the function: [querySelectorAll() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: thank you it works but I want it to be inside my javascript iterator var items = document.getElementsByClassName('CItem te1');
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
                {

Comment: Glad to be of assistance